# How do I refer to a variable stored in an array instead of its value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a set of variables which represent prices and number of items sold in a 2d array. I
 have sorted it in order to find the lowest price.

I'd like to set the second variable (number sold) of the first item (player A) to a value (200) by referring to the array.

For example:

```
var playerASold;

var arr=[
    [playerAPrice,playerASold],
    [playerBPrice,playerBSold],
    [playerCPrice,playerCSold]];

arr[0][1]=200;
```

this doesn't work, probably because `playerASold` currently has a value of 0 and it is trying to set 0=0.

**How do I refer to the variable and not the value of the variable?**

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has no notion of C's pointers or C++'s references, so you'll have to do it in a different way. Rather than trying to store references in an array, try making the array the sole holder of the data.
That might look like this:

```
var players = [
    { price: 5, sold: 1 },
    { price: 3, sold: 6 },
    { price: 9, sold: 2 }
];
```

Then rather than, say, `playerBSold`, you can use `players[1].sold`. Now you can use a variable in place of that `1` if you wanted.

Comment: The problem is that the amount sold is not set. I will determine how many are sold by figuring out who the cheapest player(s) are. I'm having 5 people enter prices into text boxes, then having javascript grab those prices and see which one(s) are lowest. I'm doing this with a sort, which re-orders the players. I then want to "buy" products from only the lowest price players and divide my stock between them. I don't see how I'd track who the winners were with this solution. That's why I wanted to keep the name of the player attached to the price. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ThomasGaskin: You could keep the name of the player with an additional `name` property, e.g., `{ name: "A", price: 5, sold: 1 }`. It's worth noting that you can add properties at any time; you could just as well set `players[1].balance` and start using it.

Comment: @ThomasGaskin: Also, making everything an array of objects like this makes sorting easy: `players.sort(function(a, b) { return a.price - b.price; });` makes the players sorted from least `price` to greatest `price`.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a close look at your code you are setting value to array.you are replacing arr[0][1] item value.previously it was playerASold i.e 0 and now 200.So you are not assigning value to playerSold.do like this:

```
var arr=[[playerAPrice:0,playerASold:0],[playerBPrice:0,playerBSold:0],   [playerCPrice:0,playerCSold:0]];
```

and use this:

```
arr[0].playerASold=200.
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript primitives (in this case Number) are immutable.  I.e., you can't change their values.  Operations on Numbers create new numbers.  Objects are however mutable.

As icktoofay suggested, refactoring as mutable Player objects with price and sold properties is probably a good idea here.